# How to limit the data points to get display in highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, frontend, zk

I have a requirement to limit the data points in highchart when it displayed due to space issue. Let's say if I have 100 data points in one series. I just want to display first 5 and when clicking on the expand button(I need to add a expand button in the chart) the highchart will display with all 100 points. (The expanded view  will be in a modal window and the modal window will have the full  hight).

I know the series are complex like,  I  can have multiple series in the to chart like this

```
series: [{
        name: 'Year 1800',
        data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Year 1900',
        data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
    }, {
        name: 'Year 2012',
        data: [1052, 954, 4250, 740, 38]
    }]
```

and I can have complex data model like this

1.`data: [1052, 954, 4250, 740, 38]`
2.`data: [[5, 2], [6, 3], [8, 2]]`
3.

```
data: [{
    name: 'Point 1',
    color: '#00FF00',
    y: 0
}, {
    name: 'Point 2',
    color: '#FF00FF',
    y: 5
}]
```

Note: Am not setting the series, am creating a widget in JavaScript which includes Highchart inside it. I can override the Highchart code for this.

Comment: You can slice the data to include only its limited amount and update the chart with setData() (or you can create a completely new chart with new data) - http://jsfiddle.net/4nn2Leoz/ - or you can set axis min/max - http://jsfiddle.net/4nn2Leoz/1/